# Unable to connect to my AWS database from workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a node server where I used an ORM that creates the tables of my database whenever the models are run. Currently, I am trying to access my RDS instance on AWS to create the database in order to run the models but I kept getting this error:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at (my endpoint URL) with user (my master user)

I made sure all my credentials are correct but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is your database set to allow remote access? Does the security group attached to the database allow inbound connections on port 3306?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I created my RDS instance, I left all the settings as default.

The default option of the **Additional Configuration > Public Access** is "*Not publicly accessible*", which caused the connection error.

Changing it to "*Publicly Accessible*" fixes this issue.

See: [Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html)